# Can't assign delegate methods to UIViews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I defined a simple CollectionView view,

When I place the delegate methods in a ViewController, the cells are displayed correctly. However, when I moved it to a UIView, none of the delegate methods are called.

Anyone knows why? Attached the code.

In the ViewController, `viewDidLoad` method,

```
self.userGrid = [[UserGrid alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
```

UserGrid.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AvatarViewCell.h"
#import "GridViewLayout.h"

@interface UserGrid : UIView <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

@end
```

And UserGrid.m

```
#import "UserGrid.h"

@implementation UserGrid

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect
{
    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"AvatarViewCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"avatarCell"];

    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:aRect])) {
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
        self.collectionView.delegate   = self;

        [self.collectionView registerClass:[AvatarViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"avatarCell"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 12;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"avatarCell";

    AvatarViewCell *avatarCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [avatarCell.avatarImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"website_%ld.jpg", indexPath.row + 1]]];

    return avatarCell;
}

@end
```

** EDIT

I changed the init part to (in viewDidLoad),

```
self.userGrid = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UserGrid" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
self.userGrid.frame = self.view.frame;
```

Added in viewDidAppear,

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.userGrid.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Added awakeFromNib method, but delegate methods are not called ... hmm

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"AvatarViewCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"avatarCell"];

    NSLog(@"awake");
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.collectionView.delegate   = self;

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[AvatarViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"avatarCell"];
}
```

Comment: Check that in initwithFrame that the collectionview is initialized or not when you are assigning delegate

Comment: @AhmadIshfaq Hmm, I have a xib file so it is initialized .. otherwise it would just crash I guess ...

Comment: Just put a break point and check and if its nil try putting these all statements in awakefromnib() function

Comment: @AhmadIshfaq awakefromnib is not called. I've added NSLog to verify that ...

Comment: It should get called if your view is associated with a xib i think that's is where your issue is.

Comment: I see the code of how you initialized the view you didn't associate the nib with view

Answer (score 1):

Initialize UserGrid view like this

```
    self.userGrid=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yourxibName" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
    self.userGrid.frame=self.view.frame;
```

You have an IBOutlet of collectionview but have not attached the view to your class so collection won't get initialized

Comment: in the controller in viewdidappear just try a collectionview reload does it work

Comment: That should work, check the outlet of collectionview is it connected